# Difference between if(value) and if(value.present?) in ruby? (Implicit conversions in if statements)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After running some code with the input: `array = [nil, false, [], {}, {a: 1}, "", [0], [nil], NoMethodError]`

```
def same_value?(value)
   a = false
   b = false

   if value
     a = true
   end

   if value.present?
     b = true
   end
   [value, a == b]
end
```

```
array.map { |v| v.same_value? }
```

I receive the response  => `[[nil, true], [false, true], [[], false], [{}, false], [{:a=>1}, true], ["", false], [[0], true], [[nil], true], [NoMethodError, true]]`.

---

So, apparently `if value` and `if value.present?` treat `""`, `{}`, and `[]` differently, as they are containers that do exist, yet are empty. My question is- is that the only difference? What operator is ruby actually using under the hood when doing the implicit condition check for `if value`? Is there some documentation or term I could look up to find more information about this implicit conversion, and the generalized case?

Comment: `Object#present?` is not in the [Ruby core](https://ruby-doc.org/3.3.0.rc1/table_of_contents.html#methods).

Comment: `if value`  succeeds unless `value` is `nil` or `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, apparently `if value` and `if value.present?` treat `""`, `{}`, and `[]` differently, as they are containers that do exist, yet are empty. My question is- is that the only difference?

There is no method called `present?` in either the Ruby core library or the standard library, so it is impossible to tell what `present?` does. You will have to look at the documentation of wherever that method came from to determine what it does.

If you don't know where the method is coming from, you can ask Ruby to help you, by grabbing a reference to the method via the [`Object#method`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Object.html#method-i-method) method and using some of the methods from [the `Method` class](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Method.html) like [`Method#owner`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Method.html#method-i-owner) or [`Method#source_location`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Method.html#method-i-source_location):

```ruby
present_method = value.method(:present?)

present_method.owner
present_method.source_location
```

Based on the name, one would assume it is a predicate (typically, methods whose named ends with `?` are predicates) which checks for the presence of something.

For example, here is [the documentation of `Object#present?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F) from the [`activesupport`](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport) RubyGem:

> ## `present?()`
>
> An object is present if it’s not blank.
>
> @return [true, false]

You are asking:

> What operator is ruby actually using under the hood when doing the implicit condition check for `if value`?

None. There is no implicit conversion and no operator.

The rules for *truthiness* are really simple:

- `false` is *falsish*.
- `nil` is *falsish*.
- Everything else is *trueish*. That includes `0`, `0.0`, `''`, `[]`, `{}`.

> Is there some documentation or term I could look up to find more information about this implicit conversion, and the generalized case?

This is covered in pretty much every introductory course, book, video, or tutorial about Ruby. There are too many too name.

If you are looking for an "official" source, it gets somewhat tricky.

Unfortunately, unlike many other programming languages, the Ruby Language Specification does not exist as a single document in a single place. Ruby does not have a single formal specification that defines what certain language constructs mean.

There are several resources, the *sum* of which can be considered kind of a specification for the Ruby programming language.

Some of these resources are:

- The [ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html) – Note that the ISO Ruby Specification was written around 2009–2010 with the specific goal that all existing Ruby implementations at the time would easily be compliant. Since YARV and MacRuby only implement Ruby 1.9+ and MRI only implements Ruby 1.8 and lower and JRuby, XRuby, Ruby.NET, and IronRuby (at the time) only implemented a subset of Ruby 1.8, this means that the ISO Ruby Specification only contains features that are common to both Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9. Also, the ISO Ruby Specification was specifically intended to be minimal and only contain the features that are absolutely required for writing Ruby programs. Because of that, it does for example only specify `String`s very broadly (since they have changed significantly between Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9). It obviously also does not specify features which were added after the ISO Ruby Specification was written, such as Ractors or Pattern Matching.
  However, the definition of *truthiness* hasn't changed since the very first version of Ruby almost 30 years ago, so this part of the ISO Ruby Language Specification is still current.
- [The Ruby Spec Suite aka `ruby/spec`](https://github.com/ruby/spec/) – Note that the `ruby/spec` is unfortunately far from complete. However, I quite like it because it is written in Ruby instead of "ISO-standardese", which is much easier to read for a Rubyist, and it doubles as an executable conformance test suite.
- [*The Ruby Programming Language* by David Flanagan and Yukihiro 'matz' Matsumoto](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516177) – This book was written by David Flanagan together with Ruby's creator matz to serve as a Language Reference for Ruby.
- [*Programming Ruby* by Dave Thomas, Andy Hunt, and Chad Fowler](https://pragprog.com/titles/ruby4/programming-ruby-1-9-2-0-4th-edition/) – This book was the first English book about Ruby and served as *the* standard introduction and description of Ruby for a long time. This book also first documented the Ruby core library and standard library, and the authors donated that documentation back to the community.
- The [Ruby Issue Tracking System](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/), specifically, the [*Feature* sub-tracker](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-master/issues?tracker_id=2) – However, please note that unfortunately, the community is really, really bad at distinguishing between Tickets about the Ruby Programming Language and Tickets about the YARV Ruby Implementation: they both get intermingled in the tracker.
- The Meeting Logs of the [Ruby Developer Meetings](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14770). (Same problem: Ruby and YARV get intermingled.)
- New features are often discussed on the [mailing lists](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/community/mailing-lists/), in particular the [ruby-core (English)](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/ruby/ruby-core/index.shtml) and [ruby-dev (Japanese)](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/ruby/ruby-dev/index.shtml) mailing lists. (Same problem again.)
- The [Ruby documentation](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/) – Again, be aware that this documentation is generated from the source code of YARV and does not distinguish between features of Ruby and features of YARV.
- In the past, there were a couple of attempts of formalizing changes to the Ruby Specification, such as the [Ruby Change Request (RCR)](http://rcrchive.net/) and [Ruby Enhancement Proposal (REP)](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby/wiki/Ruby_Enhancement_Proposals) processes, both of which were unsuccessful.
- If all else fails, you need to check the source code of the popular Ruby implementations to see what they *actually* do. Please note the plural: you have to look at multiple, ideally *all*, implementations to figure out what the consensus is. Only looking at one implementation *cannot possibly tell you* whether what you are looking at is an implementation quirk of this particular implementation or is a universally agreed-upon behavior of the Ruby Language.

Here is the definition of the *truthiness* from the ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification:

> ## 6.6 Boolean values
>
> An object is classified into either a ***trueish object*** or a ***falseish object***.
>
> Only **`false`** and **`nil`** are falseish objects. **`false`** is the only instance of the class *`FalseClass`* (see 15.2.6), to which a *false-expression* evaluates (see 11.5.4.8.3). **`nil`** is the only instance of the class *`NilClass`* (see 15.2.4), to which a *nil-expression* evaluates (see 11.5.4.8.2).
>
> Objects other than **`false`** and **`nil`** are classified into trueish objects. **`true`** is the only instance of the class *`TrueClass`* (see 15.2.5), to which a *true-expression* evaluates (see 11.5.4.8.3).

Here is the definition of the *`if` expression* from the ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification:

> ## 11.5.2.2.2 The `if` expression
>
> ### Syntax
>
> *if-expression* ::
>       **`if`** *expression* *then-clause* *elsif-clause*<sup>*</sup> *else-clause*<sup>?</sup> **`end`**
>
> *then-clause* ::
>       *separator* *compound-statement*
>     | *separator*<sup>?</sup> **`then`** *compound-statement*
>
> *else-clause* ::
>       **`else`** *compound-statement*
>
> *elsif-clause* ::
>       **`elsif`** *expression* *then-clause*
>
> ### Semantics
>
> The *if-expression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Evaluate *expression*. Let **V** be the resulting value.
> 2. If **V** is a trueish object, evaluate the *compound-statement* of the *then-clause*. The value of the *if-expression* is the resulting value. In this case, *elsif-clause*s and the *else-clause*, if any, are not evaluated.
> 3. If **V** is a falseish object, and if there is no *elsif-clause* and no *else-clause*, then the value of the *if-expression* is **`nil`**.
> 4. If **V** is a falseish object, and if there is no *elsif-clause* but there is an *else-clause*, then evaluate the *compound-statement* of the *else-clause*. The value of the *if-expression* is the resulting value.
> 5. If **V** is a falseish object, and if there are one or more *elsif-clause*s, evaluate the sequence of *elsif-clause*s as follows:
>
>    1. Evaluate the *expression* of each *elsif-clause* in the order they appear in the program text, until there is an *elsif-clause* for which *expression* evaluates to a trueish object. Let
>       **T** be this *elsif-clause*.
>    2. If **T** exists, evaluate the *compound-statement* of its *then-clause*. The value of the *if-expression* is the resulting value. Other *elsif-clause*s and an *else-clause* following **T**, if any, are not evaluated.
>    3. If **T** does not exist, and if there is an *else-clause*, then evaluate the *compound-statement* of the *else-clause*. The value of the *if-expression* is the resulting value.
>    4. If **T** does not exist, and if there is no *else-clause*, then the value of the *if-expression* is **`nil`**.

And here is a link to the definition from the ruby/spec in [`language/if_spec.rb`](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/language/if_spec.rb).

Answer (score 0):

#present? is not core ruby method. it's define in Rails -> activesupport gem. So there is no comparison but The #present? method does a bit more, it also returns false if the object was a real but empty that simple if can't.

**irb core ruby without Rails activesupport gem.**

```
irb(main):009:0> true if ""
(irb):9: warning: string literal in condition
=> true
irb(main):010:0> true if []
=> true
irb(main):011:0> true if {}
=> true
irb(main):012:0> true if {}.present?
(irb):12:in `<main>': undefined method `present?' for {}:Hash (NoMethodError)
```

**irb with Rails activesupport gem.**

```
irb(main):010:0> "".present?
=> false
irb(main):011:0> [].present?
=> false
irb(main):012:0> {}.present?
=> false
```

So .present? method is validating empty object even "if" is not.